# R: Use German stopwords in tidyverse but anti_join does not work

Tags: r, stop-words, tidyverse

I try to use the tidyverse (http://tidyverse.org/) to analyse a list of German sentences. I stick to this guide (http://tidytextmining.com/).

When I try to use a list of German stop-words it just does not work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl) # read excel
library(tibble) # tobble dataframe
library(dplyr) # piping
library(stringr) # character manipulation
library(tidytext)
library(tokenizers)

data <- read_xlsx("C:/R/npsfeedback.xlsx", sheet = "Tabelle1", col_names="feedback")
data
is.tibble(data)

# tokenise
data_clean <- data %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  unnest_tokens(word,feedback)
```

This it the part causing me trouble:

```
# remove stopwords
sw <- tibble(stopwords("de"))
sw

data_clean <- data_clean %>% 
  anti_join(.,sw)
```

My topwords are in a tibble with one column and character type.
But if I try to use anti_join I get this output:

```
Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables
```

Do you know what I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to specify by which column from both dataframes you are going to antijoin, so you have something like this

```
antijoin(., sw, by = c("first_df_var" = "second_df_var"))
```

otherwise R doesn't know which columns to join by. both your dataframes need to have a common point to join by for any of the join functions

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but instead of create a new object I use the pipe operator, and used the same name as the stopword variable: "word".
This way `anti_join` join the dataframes with the same column name

```
`data_clean <- data %>%
               mutate(linenumber = row_number()) %>%
               unnest_tokens(word, feedback) %>%
               anti_join(get_stopwords(language = "de") ) %>% 
               ungroup()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Without additional arguments anti_join expects to join to dataframes with the same column name.

The trick was

```
sw <- tibble(word = stopwords("de"))
```

Or like sweetmusicality explained.

Comment: this doesn't work?